# Finding the data of object type of list by giving its index value

Tags: c#, list, api

**I have a class like:**

```
    public class UsersTest
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
    }
```

**And I want to give a parametre to my API controller.**

```
        public List<UsersTest> users = new List<UsersTest>
        {
            new UsersTest{ UserID=1, FirstName="Kamal", SecondName="Seferov"},
            new UsersTest{ UserID=2, FirstName="Orxan", SecondName="Esedov"},
            new UsersTest{ UserID=3, FirstName="Cosqun", SecondName="Isayev"},
            new UsersTest{ UserID=4, FirstName="Elvin", SecondName="Hasanov"}
        };
        public List<UsersTest> Get(int index)
        {
            return users [index]; //error
        }
```

**So when I set parametre to 3, lets say it should display 3rd index of list**

Comment: `//error` - care to elaborate on that?

Comment: I want to display lets say 3rd index of list

Comment: ...and the error is?

Comment: normally you can do it by coding like return users [index] but it is an object type of list

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/yXPqk2t)

Comment: why don't you use `users.Where(x=>x.UserId = index)`

Comment: By `index` do you really mean an index, or the `UserID`?

Comment: I should have written : public UsersTest Get(int index)

Answer (score 1):

Your function should return `UserTest` object, not a `List`:

```
public UsersTest Get(int index)
{
    return users[index];
}
```